# Why Openssl and Java generated hashes are different?

Tags: java, openssl, digital-signature, sha512, java-security

Below is my java code and openssl command  which includes certificate string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
   final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
   String c = "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";
   final byte[] shaValue = md.digest(c.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
   System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(shaValue));
   System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(shaValue));
}
```

In 1.txt, I had my certificate string.

```
openssl dgst -hex -sha512 <1.txt
```

Both are generating different values.

Could someone help me what's wrong with this?

Comment: Would someone help me to generate the same values?

Comment: Does the file contain a newline? The string does not.

Comment: @DavidConrad I could see a new line at last.

Comment: How should I get rid of it?

Comment: That depends on your editor. You can also just add the newline in Java, in which case your code produces the same hash as openssl. I just tried it.

Comment: One way to get rid of it (on unix) would be `tr -d $'\n' <1.txt >2.txt`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it..Thanks